# Error parsing XML in Hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am getting error in my XML parsing in Hibernate

The mapping file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Student" table="student" schema="db_1">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="int">
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The config file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="Student.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am getting the below error while running the code-

```
 234 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource :     Student.hbm.xml

265 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (5) : Element type "hibernate-mapping" must be declared.

265 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (6) : Element type "class" must be declared.

265 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (7) : Element type "id" must be declared.

265 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (8) : Element type "generator" must be declared.

265 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (10) : Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "property".

265 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (10) : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "property".

265 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (2) : Element type "hibernate-mapping" must be declared.

265 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (3) : Element type "class" must be declared.

281 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (4) : Element type "id" must be declared.

281 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (5) : Element type "generator" must be declared.

281 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (7) : Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "property".

281 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (7) : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "property".

Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
```

Could anyone help me and highlight the issues, eventhough I have validated the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the jars of Hibernate are added properly in your dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting the error because you've wrong `DTD` declaration in your mapping file.
Change it to the following & then try:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```